# How can I get started on programmatically analyzing web site content?

Tags: language-agnostic

I've been looking for a new hobby programming project, and I think it would be interesting to dabble in ways to programmatically gather information from websites and then analyze that data to do things like aggregate or filter it. For example, if I wanted to write an application that could take Craiglist listings and then do something like display only the ones matching a specific city not just a geographical area. That's just a simple example, but you could go as advanced and sophisticated as how Google analyzes a site's content to know how to rank it.

I know next to nothing about that subject and I think it would be fun to learn more about it, or hopefully do a very modest programming project in that topic. My problem is, I know so little that I don't even know how to find more information about the subject.

What are these types of programs called? What are some useful keywords to use when searching on Google? Where can I get some introductory reading material? Are there interesting papers I should read?

All I need is someone to disabuse me of my ignorance, so that I can do some research on my own.

Answer (score 1):

cURL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) is a good tool to fetch a website's contents and hand it off to a processor.

If you are proficient with a particular language, see if it supports cURL. If not, PHP (php.net) may be a good place to start.

When you have retrieved a website's content via cURL, you can use the language's text processing functionality to parse the data. You can use regular expressions (http://www.regular-expressions.info/) or functions such as PHP's strstr() to find and extract the particular data you seek.

Comment: This looks like a great place to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Programs that "scan" other sites are usually called [web crawlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) or spiders.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Trying to search for info without knowing the right keywords can be very difficult. This helps out a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently completed a project that uses Google Search Appliance that basically crawls the whole .com domain of the web server. 
 
GSA is very powerful tool that pretty much indexes all the urls it encounters and serves the results.

http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/60/xml_reference.html